# IBM Worklight - is Direct Update allowed by Apple's guidelines for the App Store?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I read about Worklight's Direct Update feature already. However, I still have some questions that would like to clarify:

> Q1: Is it true that Apple allows Worklight Apps to be published to APP
>   Store even there is a direct update feature?
>
> Q2: How will Apple review and monitor the Worklight Apps' content if
>   there is a huge change  after the direct update? Or, Apple does not
>   worry about the cached web resource in the application, does it?
>
> Q3: Is there any limitation or pre-condition about the direct update
>   for the web resource? For example, the major entries of html and js
>   script files must be existed... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Q1: Is it true that Apple allows Worklight Apps to be published to APP Store even there is a direct update feature?***

A1: There are existing Worklight customers that have submitted an application to the App Store and passed Apple's app submission process. For best results, make sure you use Worklight v5.0.6.1 or later.

***Q2: How will Apple review and monitor the Worklight Apps' content if there is a huge change  after the direct update? Or, Apple does not worry about the cached web resource in the application, does it?***

A2: Apple only reviews app submissions to the App Store and whether or not they follow their guidelines. They do not review future updates to the application (as long as it was not re-submitted), for example in the form of a Direct Update unless there are some extra-ordinary circumstances (like inappropriate content that was discovered afterwards, for example...)

***Q3: Is there any limitation or pre-condition about the direct update for the web resource? For example, the major entries of html and js script files must be existed... etc.***

A3: I am not entirely sure I understand the question. There is no limitation in Direct Update - this feature replaces the existing web resources of an application with new ones. The only thing I can think of is that both the Worklight Studio (that the app was created on) and Worklight Server (that the app lives on) **must be of the same version number**.

Comment: Many thanks, Idan! Your answers are very helpful for me to reply to my clients' question about Apple App Store review process for Worklight applications.

Answer (score 1):

An update.

Apple now allows code updates if you use a webview

> 3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts,
>   code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not
>   downloaded. **The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code
>   downloaded and run by Apple's built- in WebKit framework, provided
>   that such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the
>   Application** by providing features or functionality that are
>   inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the
>   Application as submitted to the App Store.