# Does Apple reject Hybrid app if it loads resources including javascript from remote server?

Tags: javascript, ios, hybrid

For some purpose, I use web technology to develop my iOS app. In order to improve the UIWebView performance, I put the resources(including html/css/javascript) locally in app bundle to reduce the loading time.

I also create a thread to check resource update, and download the newer resources if needed. Next time the app can use the resources to render web view.

This solution works well.

But I worried that whether apple will reject my app because I download javascript from remote server. Is there any hybrid app that use similar solution and appear in app store?

Answer (score 0):

You can download and execute javascript, provided that it's being executed by a UIWebView.

This is actually pretty common. If you need an example during a review (you won't), point to any alternate iOS web browser, like Chrome. They download and execute all kinds of web resources, but it's okay because they do it in a UIWebView and Apple trusts UIWebView.

That said, if you download resources that change your app's functionality in a way that would not be appropriate for an App Store product, you're likely to get it pulled and -- if the violation is egregious enough -- you may lose your developer account.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Worklight platform is using similar approach.

You can read more on this thread (and it might give you some answers):

[IBM Worklight - is Direct Update allowed by Apple's guidelines for the App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080470/ibm-worklight-is-direct-update-allowed-by-apples-guidelines-for-the-app-store)